# How can I send multiple email using a loop in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

I have a problem in my code. I want to send 10 emails from different clients. And I put my process in a loop. And every loop I update the status column to `1`. My problem is only 1 email can send. My loop doesn't proceed to the next email address. Here's my code:

```
$dummy = $this->Users_model->get_dummy_email(); //produces 10 results.

$valid_email = array();

$this->load->library('email');

$config = array(
    'protocol'  =>  'sendmail',
    'smtp_host' =>  'mail.sample.ph',
    'smtp_port' =>  587,
    'mailtype'  =>  'html', 
    'charset'   =>  'utf-8'
);

$this->email->initialize($config);
$this->email->set_mailtype("html");

foreach($dummy as $d) { //loop is ok

    $this->email->clear();

    $this->email->from('info@sample.ph', 'Admin');
    $this->email->to($d['email']);
    $this->email->cc('user@sample.ph, mymail@gmail.com');
    $this->email->subject("TEST MESSAGE ONLY USING CRON");
    $this->email->message("TEST FROM ADMIN");

    $send_mail = $this->email->send();

    if($send_mail) {

        $this->Users_model->updateDummyStatus($d['id']);
        return true;

    } else {
        echo $this->email->print_debugger();
    }

}
```

Can you help me what's my error. I tried also put the initialization inside the loop and still same effect. Only 1 email can send.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using return in your loop after sending email. the return statement immediately ends execution of the current function. So your remaining emails will not send.

```
if($send_mail) {

    $this->Users_model->updateDummyStatus($d['id']);
    //return true;   <--- Remove this line..

}
```